# Email Textarea with JavaScript URL Code

Tags: javascript, html, mailto

I'm building an application with a WebView. You don't really need to know that but it is the reason why I need this question answered, no alternate methods.

Is there anyway to put some kind of script on the same web page as the textarea object, then after typing in some kind of JavaScript code in the URL, it will open the default mail program with the user entered text from the textarea as the body part of the message.

Confusing, I know, but read it over a couple times.

(Note: when I say popup the default mail program, I mean like the same method as *mailto*, when it opens in the default mail app)

Comment: You want your users to type JavaScript code into their browser's address bar to open their mail program? ...why not just use a `mailto` link? Or ask them to open their email program using their GUI (or by whatever other means they'd normally do that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the assumption that the `textarea` has an `id="ta1"`, is this what you are looking to type into your address bar:

```
javascript:location.href="mailto:a@b.com?body="+document.getElementById("ta1").value;
```

**EDIT:**

Get the same action performed on button click:

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href=&quot;mailto:a@b.com?body=&quot;+document.getElementById(&quot;ta1&quot;).value;" value="Send">
```

*Works on Android stock browser too*

Comment: Glad it helped! Just remember though to use this sort of user input minimally and definitely not on any public facing user interface.

Comment: Be sure to escape the value from the textarea before adding it to the URL: `…+encodeURI(document.getElementById("ta1").value)`

Answer (score 1):

A `mailto` link can include the default subject / message in it using URL parameters.

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=My%20Subject&body=My%20message">
```

So, the best way to achieve what you want would be to build the URL dynamically based on the value of the `<textarea>` input element. You can then assign the URL to the `href` attribute of an anchor tag, or to `window.location` directly.

Sadly, it doesn't look like `<form action="mailto:…">` works, so you will need some JS.

Answer (score 0):

Just bind a listener to the `onkeyup` and `onchange` events for the `<textarea>` that runs a function that creates the right kind of `mailto:` link.

```
$("#sendMail").on("keyup change", function(){
    $(this).attr("href", "mailto:......");
});
```

You can specific the receipient, subject, and body like this:

```
<a id="sendMail" href="mailto:user@domain.com?subject=abcdef&body=bodyMessage">Send</a>
```

Then use some CSS to style the link to look like a button. E.g.

```
#sendMail { display: block; background: #EEE; border: 1px solid #CCC; color: #000; }
```